# JavaScript -Get part of an element's string from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this array

`const array = ['item-30', 'part-12', 'list-41'];`

What I need is to order these from smallest to largest based on the suffix of each element

Example:

- part-12
- item-30
- list-41

As you can see from the list above the elements in the array array are showing up in order based on the suffix of the string (i.e. -12, -30, -40)

In addition I need the elements to be in order. BUT without the prefix in the string

Example:

- part
- item
- list

So now the array is in order, minus the (-suffix).

I tried the following:

```
const array = ['item-30', 'part-12', 'list-41'];
console.log(array.sort((a, b) => a < b ? 1 : 1));
```

I really hope this makes sense. :D

Comment: Post the JavaScript that you have tried but failed to get it to work, see [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: ```const fruits = ['item-30', 'part-12', 'list-41']
console.log(fruits.sort((a, b) => a < b ? 1 : 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

`sort`, `map`, `split` are used to solve this.

```js
const fruits = ['item-30', 'part-12', 'list-41'];
var result = fruits.sort((a, b) => Number(a.split("-")[1]) - Number(b.split("-")[1])).map(a => a.split("-")[0])
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

When `sort()`ing numbers, the callback is simply `a - b`. To get these numbers we will `.slice(-2)` the last two characters of each string then coerce that string into a number by prefixing them with a `+`:

```
.sort((a, b) => +a.slice(-2) - +b.slice(-2))
```

Next, `.map()` each string and on each iteration `.replace()` a *literal*: `-` and *"one or more digits"*: `\d+` on the current string with *nothing*: `''`:

```
.map(x => x.replace(/-\d+/, ''));
```

```js
let array = ['item-30', 'part-12', 'list-41'];
let output = array
  .sort((a, b) => +a.slice(-2) - +b.slice(-2))
  .map(x => x.replace(/-\d+/, '')); 
console.log(output);
```